# How can I authenticate users without forcing them to register?

Tags: php

I want to make a website that I thought up, but I don't want to have the users register. Instead, I want some sort of unique id that can be retrieved using PHP. This unique ID could be to be with the network they are using, or their computer.

One idea I was thinking of was getting the users HWID and using that. Would that be possible?

Can someone give me the advantages and disadvantages of doing this, and also give me some examples of what I could use?

Comment: Why don't you just use OpenID, the same thing you used for this website?

Comment: it's called cookies :) But you need to know php first. And programming. And computers :P

Comment: @N.B. I don't really want to use any third-party code. I prefer to make things myself, and learn about it at the same time.

Comment: @SpyrosP That would probably work, but I was hoping for something a little more permanent, because if the user cleared their cookies. The information I want to display would no longer be displayed. Correct?

Comment: Correct, but there is no other persistant way really.

Comment: @DuncanPalmer that is correct. But then again, what did you expect? The server cannot identify a client absolutely. What if the same user were to switch his computer? Or attempt to use your service from a friend's computer. That's the point of registration and login.

Comment: @Truth Fair enough. I think I might just make a login, atleast now I know a few ways of ever being able to do it.

Comment: @DuncanPalmer - at least read what OpenID is. It's not "third party code".

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is very similar to PHP sessions. A user is given a unique ID, and on the server side the unique ID is assigned variables (in the form of the `$_SESSION` superglobal). The user will then send the unique ID with every request (be it with a cookie or a get variable), and PHP will fetch the variables and set the proper `$_SESSION` array.

This is somewhat problematic in terms of security. The session ID can be stolen (over insecure WiFi for instance), and then the server will wrongly identify the attacker as the victim (in case of administration and limited access, this is problematic). Nothing beats a good username/passphrase combo to secure an area.

If no sensitive information is stored, than by all means sessions are a very good solution.

**[See the PHP manual about sessions.](http://il.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)**

---

You should note though, if the user will erase his cookies (if the session ID is transferred via a cookie), or clear the URL from variables (in case of GET variable), the session will expire, and the user will no longer be recognized. A server cannot absolutely identify a client. What if the user would format/switch computers? Or what if he wishes to use your service from another computer? If those are the cases, then you want to use a registration and login system.

Comment: The problem with session in this case is when the session expires there's no way to authenticate the same user again with the same data it had.

Comment: Yes, I've just added that information. In that case you want something more permanent such as registration and login.